# Using Cordova CLI to create iOS and Android apps with different application id's

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I currently have an android and iOS app built using Sencha Touch 2, packaged with PhoneGap and any platform specific dependencies are manually swapped out before building and releasing... it all works but it is not the most straight forward process.

I've been looking at trying to simply the process and the cordova CLI looks very promising (can support both platforms directly and platform specific dependencies are dealt with via the merges hierarchy) but I've have other stumbling block in that the live app has a different application id in both Google Play and iTunes app store so I'm not able to specify this simply in the global config.xml.

Are you able to specify an application id per platform i.e. via the merges hierarchy or any other way so I don't have to worry about any manual changes when I'm running cordova build?

Answer (score 0):

Since I came across the same issue a while ago, I can tell you I didn't find a solution with the built-in Cordova tools or config.xml to generate different platforms with different application id's automatically.

Anyway, if you can use a Taskrunner like `grunt` for building and packaging your app, you can achieve this easily by taking the grunt-plugin [grunt-phonegap](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-phonegap).

For example configure `grunt` similar like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    ...
    dir: {
        root: '/',
        build: '<%= dir.path.local%>',
        path: {
            local: '/home/user/project/myapp/',
            bundleId: '',
            bundleIdIos: 'bundle.ios.app',
            bundleIdAndroid: 'bundle.android.app'
        },
    },
    ...
    phonegap: {
        config: {
            root: '<%=  dir.dist.app %>',
            config: {
                template: '<%= dir.src.app %>/phonegap/_myConfig.xml',
                data: {
                    id: 'com.example.<%= dir.path.bundleId %>',
                    name: 'exampleApp'
                }
            },
        },
    },
    ...
```

Then you can run the build-jobs with the corresponding app id's like the following:

```
    grunt.registerTask('build-app', 'Runs build-app task', function (target) {
    if (target === 'ios') {
        grunt.config.set('dir.path.build', grunt.config.get('dir.path.local'));
        grunt.config.set('dir.path.bundleId', grunt.config.get('dir.path.bundleIdIos'));
    }
    if (target === 'android') {
        grunt.config.set('dir.path.build', grunt.config.get('dir.path.local'));
        grunt.config.set('dir.path.bundleId', grunt.config.get('dir.path.bundleIdAndroid'));
    }
    grunt.task.run('phonegap-build');
});
```

This setup worked for me some time ago.

Alternatively, you could modify the package variable in the Android Manifest file after the build and package it again on commandline with `ant debug` from the Android Debug-Tools (possibly even automatically with a little script and a XML-Parser).